# My Q# language server won't stop downloading on VS Code

Tags: q#

I'm trying to create a Q# New Project in VS Code, but VS Code won't let me do that until I have my Q# language server downloaded.

I'm using a mac. And the Q# language server just kept downloading for hours.

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The language server is what provides most of the functionality for VS Code, it is about 38Mb so it shouldn't take that long to download, maybe there is some flaky with your network?

As a workaround, you can try using the instructions from the ["Other editors from the command line" in the setup instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/quantum/quickstarts/install-command-line?tabs=tabid-cmdline), that explains how to create a new Q# project directly from the command line, which then you can open in VS Code.